# В консоль вместо русских букв выводятся символы вопросов Python

Tags: python, кодировка

Если использовать команду `print()`, то всё работает нормально но когда питон принимает русские буквы из системной консоли то он выводит не пойми что

[image: Пример]

Comment: В какой кодировке `.py` файл у вас? И какая операционка, в какой кодировке у неё консоль?

Comment: @CrazyElf система Win10, консоль - DOS, а как определить кодировку `.py` файла я не знаю. Если вы знаете способ, скиньте ссылку пожалуйста потому что я нахожу только вопросы о том как через питон определить кодировку текстового файла

Comment: @ЕжиСармат Запустите скрипт в консоли и проблема с кодировкой скоре всего решится... а PyCharm это PYCharm в нем свои фишки(косяки),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.system` возвращает только код завершения программы (0 это успех, не 0 - ошибка). В вашей программе os.system возвращает 0, который вы сохраняете в переменную `disk`. Так же, `os.system` не перенаправляет вывод (попробуйте убрать принт, исчезнет только 0, кракозяблы останутся).
Я думаю, вам подойдёт функция `subprocess.check_output`

```
import subprocess


# функция возвращает двоичные данные, потому надо использовать decode
# cp866 - стандартная кодировка windows
disk = subprocess.check_output("wmic logicaldisk get description,name").decode('cp866')
```

И совет на будущее: пожалуйста, оставляйте свой код в вопросе в виде текста, так вам будет намного проще помочь)

Comment: у меня почему то ничего не выводит, даже ноль не показывает, а если точнее то просто пустоту выводит

Comment: Видимо с этой командой ваша функция не работает но я нашел другую `fsutil fsinfo drives`, она работает отлично, разве что названия дисков не выводит а только их букву

Comment: Проверяли переменную `disk`? Я лично запускал на моем компьютере, весь вывод сохранялся в неё.

Answer (score 0):

мне это помогло:

```
STR.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866')
```